# Increase the default number of breaks for ggplot scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I like to make a ggplot theme where the default number of axis breaks is double the default. I'm not sure what setting to update. I can see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486102/how-does-ggplot-calculate-its-default-breaks) that ggplot calculates the breaks using `labeling::extended`. From the doc I can see that the argument `m` controls the number of breaks:

> Usage
> extended(dmin, dmax, m, Q = c(1, 5, 2, 2.5, 4, 3),
> only.loose = FALSE, w = c(0.25, 0.2, 0.5, 0.05))

> m  number of axis labels

This gets passed from `scales::extended_breaks` which I can see has the default set to 5:

```
 function (n = 5, ...) 
    {
        n_default <- n
        function(x, n = n_default) {
            x <- x[is.finite(x)]
            if (length(x) == 0) {
                return(numeric())
            }
            rng <- range(x)
            labeling::extended(rng[1], rng[2], n, ...)
        }
    }
```

So is there a theme setting I could change to default n to e.g. 10?

```
theme_more_ticks <- function(nticks = 10) {
    theme_minimal() +
    ...?
}
```

I know that breaks for an individual plot can be changed in many ways [(ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040066/change-axis-breaks-without-defining-sequence-ggplot). However,  I would like all plots I produce with this theme to have double the number of breaks they would have with the default theme.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but why not use the `breaks` argument in the appropriate `scale_xxx_yyy` function?

Comment: I want to change the default setting instead of adding `scale_xxx_yyy` to every plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies.  I overlooked the word "theme" in the first line of your post.

I don't think you can do what you want using themes, because as I understand it, themes affect the appearance of `ggplot2` elements, not the algorithms used to calculate their number, position, values etc.  The best I could do was to modify the functions used to construct the ggplot object.  For example

```
mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=cyl, y=mpg))
```

gives

[image]

But

```
scale_x_continuous <- function(...) ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(..., breaks=scales::extended_breaks(n=10, ...))
mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=cyl, y=mpg))
```

produces

[image]

So rather than redefining the `theme`, overwrite the various `scale_xxxx_yyyy` functions.  That's a similar one-off task to redefining the default `theme`.

Check my handling of `...`.  I've not checked it and I've got it wrong in the past.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes I think that will work nicely. I'll give it a blast in my use case.

Comment: Actually I think the second set of `...`s need removing to make it work

Comment: If I leave them in lots of stuff breaks but with them out it seems ok.